# Hook to filter content before rendering in TYPO3 via Extbase?

Tags: hook, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

I need to filter content from tt_content by some criteria, before Typo3 renders it
Probably by a hook.

Is there such a hook in typo3 6.1.6? And how can I use it?

Is it in

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class']['t3lib_pagerenderer']['php'] = '';
```

or

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class']['tslib_content']['php'] = '';
```

I know How can I include and register my class in my extension, but what I dont know is where in `TYPO_3_CONF_VARS` in this case.

I have used the native category system and developed extension with plugin, which show content only from the selected category(ies). Now I need to filter content on each page, to dont display content, whis is in desired category. The desired category is setup in EM config

Comment: If you could elaborate on what you exactly want to do (what kind of filter?) I could help you more precisely.

Comment: Hi lorenz, I have used the native category system and developed extension with plugin, which show content only from the selected category(ies).
Now I need to filter content on each page, to dont display content, whis is in desired category. The desired category is setup in EM config.

Comment: If you have already written code (extension), why don't you do your filter magic there? How do you output the content to the browser? If you use some typoscript like `styles.content.get`, you could modify there where clause for the tt_content select query in your typoscript.